# Code returns"The Name 'noiseMap' does not exist in current context"

Tags: c#

Noise map is being called from a separate script called `NoiseMapGeneration`, and noiseMap method is public.

Please someone help me I have been reading this over and over for an hour; I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I am using these scripts in unity and testing this section.

```
public class TileGeneration : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    NoiseMapGeneration noiseMapGeneration;

    [SerializeField]
    private MeshRenderer tileRenderer;

    [SerializeField]
    private MeshFilter meshFilter;

    [SerializeField]
    private MeshCollider meshCollider;

    [SerializeField]
    private float mapScale;

    void Start()
    {
        GenerateTile();
    }

    void GenerateTile()
    {
        // vertices
        Vector3[] meshVertices = this.meshFilter.mesh.vertices;
        int tileDepth = (int)Mathf.Sqrt(meshVertices.Length);
        int tileWidth = tileDepth;

        float[,] heightMap = this.noiseMapGeneration.GenerateNoiseMap(tileDepth, tileWidth, this.mapScale);

        Texture2D tileTexture = BuildTexture(heightMap);
        this.tileRenderer.material.mainTexture = tileTexture;
    }

    private Texture2D BuildTexture(float[,] heightMap)
    {
        int tileDepth = noiseMap.GetLength(0);
        int tileWidth = noiseMap.GetLength(1);

        Color[] colorMap = new Color[tileDepth * tileWidth];

        for (int zIndex = 0; zIndex < tileDepth; zIndex++)
        {
            for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < tileWidth; xIndex++)
            {
                // transform the 2D map index is an Array index
                int colorIndex = zIndex * tileWidth + xIndex;
                float height = heightMap[zIndex, xIndex];

                colorMap[colorIndex] = Color.Lerp(Color.black, Color.white, height);
            }
        }

        Texture2D tileTexture = new Texture2D(tileWidth, tileDepth);
        tileTexture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        tileTexture.SetPixels(colorMap);
        tileTexture.Apply();

        return tileTexture;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Unity? Could you post your NoiseMap code? Are you missing a reference to the script? How do you set the NoiseMapGeneration field?

Comment: You reference a variable called `noiseMap` in the `BuildTexture` method. Where is that variable defined? I don't see it defined in this code snippet. That would explain the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

For future people who find this. The issue in the tutorial is they changed the name between the two functions. change noiseMap to heightMap

This is where it is set

```
     float[,] heightMap = this.noiseMapGeneration.GenerateNoiseMap(tileDepth, tileWidth, this.mapScale);
```

And this is where they call it

```
    int tileDepth = noiseMap.GetLength(0);
    int tileWidth = noiseMap.GetLength(1);
```

So make it

```
    int tileDepth = heightMap.GetLength(0);
    int tileWidth = heightMap.GetLength(1);
```